# Dynamic linking GLFW with make

Tags: glfw

I am trying to compile a simple tutorial program utilising glfw with minimal opengl.  My issue appears to be that the glfw library is stubbornly refusing to be dynamically linked.  The relevant make command is:

```
"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin\g++" -Wall -m64 -D GLFW_DLL -l opengl32 -l glfw3 main.o -o triangle <br />
```

The main.o file is compiled from a c++ file, main.cpp by:

```
"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin\g++" -c -Wall -m64 -D GLFW_DLL main.cpp -o main.o
```

Every reference to the glfw functions made inside the code is causing an undefined reference to the relevant implementation functions (eg. __imp_glfwInit for glfwInit => undefined reference to '__imp_glfwInit')
Build system is mingw-w64 [windows] using make via the command line, with glfw 3.0.4.  The glfw lib is 64 bit and the latest stable build avaliable.  It consists of the files:

- glfw3.dll
- glfw3dll.a
- libglfw3.a 
  Which are the 'WIN-64' 'lib-mingw'
  After extensive searches (GLFW help pages useless[deal either with 2.7.2 which doesn't apply or doesn't have useful information in the case of 3.0.4], most of stackoverflow deals with static linking, ect) I have been unable to find a solution which works.  
  Is there something I am missing dealing with the linker that is not making me able to dynamically link?  
  Clarification on any errors I am making or a solution of some form that would still allow me to use the dynamic libraries would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the provided files do not work with mingw-w64, and are only compatible with 64bit mingw.
Thus the only option left is linking against the dll (with thanks to greatwolf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17734362/2396393).  The code to compile to objects thus became:

```
"C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin\g++" -Wall -m64 -D GLFW_DLL main.o -o triangle ./lib/glfw3.dll -l opengl32
```

Where the dll glfw3 is located in the lib folder